# Print login detail of user who logged into system and modified a program

Tags: python

Suppose:
My system login ID is tom2deu.
I have one Python program.
Now I am going to modified this Python program.

My question:

Can we print my login ID to a seprate notepad or any other file?
ie. can we print any person detail (login ID) who had logged the system and modified the program?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what problem you're trying to solve, but if you want to track changes to source files you should probably use a version control system such as [Subversion](http://subversion.tigris.org/). In a nutshell, it will track all the changes to your source files and also manage conflicts (when two people try to change a file at the same time).

Answer (score 2):

If you want a general solution you should take [`pyinotify`](http://pyinotify.sourceforge.net/), which is a wrapper for the Linux kernel's [`inotify`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) feature (kernel version >= 2.6.13). With it you can register for certain events in the filesystem, like e.g. in the following code:

```
from pyinotify import WatchManager, ThreadedNotifier, ProcessEvent, EventsCodes

file_to_monitor = "/tmp/test.py"

class FSEventHook(ProcessEvent):
    def __init__(self, watch_path):
        ProcessEvent.__init__(self)

        wm = WatchManager()
        wm.add_watch(watch_path, EventsCodes.ALL_FLAGS['IN_CLOSE_WRITE'], rec=False)
        self.notifier = ThreadedNotifier(wm, self)

    def start(self):
        self.notifier.start()

    def process_IN_CLOSE_WRITE(self, event):
        if os.path.isfile(event.pathname):
            print "%s changed"%pathname

fshook = FSEventHook(file_to_monitor)
fshook.start()
```

The following events are supported: `IN_MOVED_FROM, IN_CREATE, IN_ONESHOT, IN_IGNORED, IN_ONLYDIR, IN_Q_OVERFLOW, IN_MOVED_TO, IN_DELETE, IN_DONT_FOLLOW, IN_CLOSE_WRITE, IN_MOVE_SELF, IN_ACCESS, IN_MODIFY, IN_MASK_ADD, IN_CLOSE_NOWRITE, IN_ISDIR, IN_UNMOUNT, IN_DELETE_SELF, ALL_EVENTS, IN_OPEN, IN_ATTRIB`. For each of them you have to implement its own `process_XXX()` method, which will be called back if the event is triggered.

Answer (score 1):

try these..

import os
print os.environ['USERNAME']

or

os.getlogin()

then save in a variable and use file handling to store it as a text file..

Comment: I don't think that's what he's asking.  I think he wants to know who last edited the file in question.

Comment: And, as far as I know, he can't.  He can find out who created the file and who has permission to write to it, but not who last saved it.

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking is if you can track who made changes to a file. And that's not a Python question, but a question of the operating system. To be able to track who changed a file, you need to have an auditing system installed. If you use Linux, it has an audit subsystem that you can configure to track this information, I think.