# Python Script Executed with Makefile

Tags: python, makefile

I am writing python scripts and execute them in a Makefile. The python script is used to process data in a pipeline. I would like Makefile to execute the script every time I make a change to my python scripts.

Does anyone have an idea of how to do this?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

That's not a lot of information, so this answer is a bit vague. The basic principle of Makefiles is to list dependencies for each target; in this case, your target (let's call it foo) depends on your python script (let's call it do-foo.py):

```
foo: do-foo.py
    python do-foo.py > foo
```

Now foo will be rerun whenever do-foo.py changes (provided, of course, you call make).

Comment: I did not define the dependency to my .py files correctly in my script. thanks

Comment: As a note, even though the question is effectively self-resolved, I'd like to expand on this answer. You can also define bytecode compilation as a target using invocations of `python -m compileall` to produce the target `pyc/pyo` files.

Answer (score 4):

And in case when the scripts that need to be run don't produce any useful output file that can be used as a target, you can just use a dummy target:

```
scripts=a.py b.py c.py
checkfile=.pipeline_up_to_date

$(checkfile): $(scripts)
    touch $(checkfile)
    echo "Launching some commands now."

default: $(checkfile)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want that Makefile to be automatically "maked" immediately after saving, [`pyinotify`](http://pyinotify.sourceforge.net/), which is a wrapper for [`inotify`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify), might be the only possibility under Linux. It registers at the kernel to detect FS changes and calls back your function.

See my [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1030966/login-input/1031130#1031130) on that topic.

Comment: good to know! but I think I my question was a little bit unclear it was more a makefile question. Thanks anyway!