# Makefile for python scripts

Tags: python, unix, makefile

I have files to send but I am a little bit confused on how to do it. I had to write two codes in python (say A.py and B.py) and it is required to create a Makefile such that typing "make" in bash in the folder would create the executables for A and B. I do not have Unix and I never used it. I'm a Windows user.
Is this something I should write in my .py files? And how can I check if I am doing it right if I'm on Windows?
I saw this post [Python Script Executed with Makefile](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1062436/python-script-executed-with-makefile) but I am not sure to understand how this works.
Thank you for your help

Comment: Nothing in your Python code needs to know that `make` is being used. Your Makefile simply describes the commands you would otherwise run at the command line to build your executable, whatever those might be.

Comment: Do you want to compile the .py files to .pyc files? Python isn't typically compiled with makefiles like typical unix executables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python is interpreted language - it doesn't produce executables like C or C++ would do. The source code itself "is executable". To execute program `A.py` you need to run command `python A.py`.

On *nix systems, you can omit the need of writing `python` every time and make file itself executable by adding so called shebang (`#!/usr/bin/env python`) at the top of script and adding executable flag with `chmod +x A.py` (only once). Now script could be executed just with `./A.py` (or `A.py` if the directory containing it is in `PATH` environment variable).

Makefile can execute commands, just as the shell script can do (obliviously there are differences, but it's not important for now). So if you want to execute your scripts with `make`, you can just do:

```
foo: A.py B.py
    python A.py
    python B.py
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Jorengarenar. I have the same question as above: where should I write the code you are mentioning? Is it in a file that I should attach along with my two .py files? And is this a file format I can create using windows?

Comment: The code for `make` should be in Makefile. Shebang should go at top of Python sccript (note I've shared here a \*nix version, for Windows will be different).

Answer (score 3):

Let's take the example you shared in a link.

```
foo: do-foo.py
    python do-foo.py
```

Makefile is like a cookbook. To create a dish `foo` you need an ingredient `do-foo.py`. If `do-foo.py` is present then the Makefile can execute python script `python do-foo.py`, which will cook a dish `foo` (execute it). If not, the script will not be executed and a `foo` dish not cooked.

With this similar analogy in your example you would do:

```
all: exe_A exe_B

exe_A: A.py 
    python A.py

exe_B: B.py 
    python B.py
```

> And how can I check if I am doing it right if I'm on Windows?

To check it, I would recommend that you install a UNIX simulator on windows called Cygwin. And then run it from there as `make all`. There are tutorials on it.

**EDIT:** Corrected my mistake pointed out by Jorengarenar

Comment: Thanks a lot - but where should I write the code you are mentioning? Is it a file that I should attach along with my two .py files? And is this a file format I can create using windows?

Comment: Makefile is a standalone file that is used to automate compilation among others. Inside `Makefile` file you include the script I wrote above `all: exe_A ...`. Then in the UNIX environment, you could call `make all` command which would trigger the `Makefile` file script. Here are some options on how to run this `Makefile` file on windows -> [link](https://vispud.blogspot.com/2019/02/how-to-run-makefile-in-windows.html)

Comment: Command `python do-foo.py > foo` doesn't create executable. It executes script `do-foo.py` and redirects output to file `foo`.